# Delphi Indy Cliente envía paquetes de 64 KB y el Server recibe 2 paquetes que suman 64 KB

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

Con el componente `TIDTCPServer` de Indy en Delphi se recibe un paquete fraccionado que el cliente envió de 64 KB.

¿Cómo recibo el paquete completo en el evento Execute del Server?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes control de esto, TCP **no es un protocolo orientado a mensajes**, sino un **protocolo orientado al flujo de datos** (no sabría como traducir: [*stream based protocol*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017633/difference-between-message-oriented-protocols-and-stream-oriented-protocols)).

En otras palabras, el stack TCP, en cualquier punto (puede ser la propia tarjeta de red del cliente, routers, switch, hubs, etc.) puede dividir un *mensaje* en la cantidad de *paquetes* que considere convenientes (y regularmente lo hace, por ejemplo a medida que los paquetes van atravesando redes *antiguas* con diferentes capacidades, velocidades o incluso que funcionan sobre protocolos distintos a TCP).

Otra forma de verlo, es que si tu envías los siguientes *mensajes*

- ABC
- DEF

En el cliente, podrías recibir todas las combinaciones de secuencias, por citar algunos ejemplos:

- ABCDEF
- ABC DEF
- A BCD EF
- A BCDEF
- ABCDE F
- Y una larga lista de etcéteras

De hecho, hablando de tu pregunta particular, ninguna red que yo conozca sería capaz de transmitir 64 Kb en un solo paquete, el hecho de que tu veas solo dos *paquetes* es una mera casualidad y producto de la red y equipo particular dónde te encuentras ejecutando tu cliente o servidor, pero en otra red, otro equipo, incluso el mismo equipo bajo condiciones distintas, muy probablemente verías un comportamiento distinto.

Es normal diseñar, sobre TCP, protocolos (de más alto nivel) orientados a mensajes, pero en este caso, para implementar las soluciones debes tener en mente como funciona el protocolo subyacente.

Suena más complicado de lo que es, hay básicamente tres formas de trabajo.

- Si vas a recibir *mensajes* de longitud fija, en un ciclo lees datos, y simplemente sigues a la espera de más datos hasta que se complete un nuevo mensaje. Hay protocolos que están en este ciclo hasta que reciben un *mensaje* con el cual terminar la comunicación. Cada vez que completas un mensaje, lo procesas, y sigues en el ciclo esperando más mensajes.
- Si vas a recibir *mensajes* de longitud variable, una técnica bastante común es enviar primero la longitud en bytes del mensaje que se enviará (que es un dato de longitud fija). En el otro punto, lees primero este dato, y luego, pues, ya sabes cuantos bytes esperar antes de terminar la comunicación o de dar por completado ese nuevo mensaje.
- En protocolos donde hay un flujo continuo de información, regularmente se establecen secuencias de bytes que indican el inicio o fin de los mensajes o de la comunicación. Todo el tiempo el receptor está inspeccionando los datos recibidos hasta encontrar una de estas secuencias y actuar en consecuencia.

Hay muchos ejemplos de todos estos tipos en el Internet de hoy.

Suponiendo el caso de *mensajes* de longitud fija, y tomando tu ejemplo de 64Kb, la manera más simple de implementarlo (solo para efectos ilustrativos), es hacer muy *grande* el ReadTimeout, y que el propio componente `TidTCPServer` se encargue de esperar hasta lograr leer los 64Kb, por ejemplo:

```
function TForm1.BytesToHex(const AData; Size: Cardinal): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  B: pByte;
const
  Digits : array [0..15] of char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
begin
  Result := '';
  B := @AData;
  for I := 0 to Size - 1 do
  begin
    Result := Result + Digits[B^ shr 4] + Digits[B^ and 15];
    if ((I + 1) mod 4) = 0 then
      Result := Result + ' ';
    Inc(B);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Data: TidBytes;
  strData: string;
begin
  SetLength(Data, 64 * 1024);
  //no es recomendable hacer esto en producción, es solo un ejemplo
  //Establecer el ReadTimeout a 60 segundos podría romper ciertas cosas
  //pues el sistema esperará hasta 60 segundos por cada siguiente paquete
  //que potencialmente podría ser de hasta 1 byte de longitud, haciendo
  //la espera realmente larga para un _mensaje_ de 64Kb
  //en una red lenta.
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 60000;
  while AContext.Connection.Connected do
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Data, Length(Data), False);
    strData := BytesToHex(Data[0], Length(Data));
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(strData);
        Inc(FNumeroMensajes);
        Label1.Caption := IntToStr(FNumeroMensajes);
      end);
  end;
end;
```

Puedes probar *fácilmente* la teoría, haciendo un solo *envío* de 1Mb, desde un cliente, como este:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Datos: TidBytes;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Inc(FNumeroMensaje);
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  try
    SetLength(Datos, 1024 * 1024);
    for I := Low(Datos) to High(Datos) do
      Datos[I] := FNumeroMensaje;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Datos);
  finally
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Esto, produce que el contador de mensajes en el servidor se dispare a 16. Ya con el código de ejemplo, puedes jugar y enviar, por ejemplo, paquetes de 8Kb, esperar unos cuantos segundos y enviar otro paquete, y verás cómo el servidor los sigue leyendo en fragmentos de 64Kb.

[image: Salida de una ejecución del código de ejemplo]

Comment: jachguate 
La situación es que tengo un servidor que recibe notificaciones de transacciones que debe grabar en BD. Algunas superan los 8 KB. Con un prototipo se presentan casos en que al Execute del server llegan los paquetes fraccionados. Dado que cada paquete no tiene la longitud. De qué forma recibo cada paquete completo?
Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: GBM, si lees con detenimiento mi respuesta, explico como puedes manejar los casos de mensajes de longitud variable. Lo que debes aprender (y aceptar) es que estos pueden llegar fragmentados o incluso _mezclados_ con otros mensajes que hay podido enviar el mismo cliente, en la misma conexión (no se si sea tu caso). Con esta idea en mente, ya te toca a ti desarrollar un mecanismo para a) diferenciar un mensaje de otro (explico en el post como puedes hacerlo), b) Mantenerte en un ciclo en el que lees tantas veces como sea necesario hasta completar un _mensaje_ y procesarlo.

Comment: Teniendo en mente que un mensaje puede venir en X fragmentos, o que un solo fragmento puede traer partes de distintos mensajes. Lo que TCP **si** te garantiza es que los bytes enviados por el cliente llegarán a) integros b) en el mismo orden en el que fueron enviados.

Comment: Finalmente, diría que tu duda original está respondida. Puedes escribir una nueva pregunta para profundizar en el tema de como manejar el caso específico de los mensajes de longitud variable. (Idealmente después de haber intentado escribir el código para hacerlo, de manera que puedas venir con preguntas y ejemplos concretos), y no olvides incluir toda la información que sea pertinente en la pregunta para obtener una respuesta aplicable a tu situación particular.

Comment: jachguate. A fin de precisar más, anexé el código del cliente y del server con el cual se simula la situación.

Comment: GBM, ¿a dónde lo anexaste?

Comment: A la ventana del caso, pero tengo el siguiente mensaje:
¡Gracias por tu edición!
Esta edición será visible solo para ti hasta que sea revisada por pares.

Comment: gracias por su ayuda. Voy a abrir una nueva pregunta con el código del prototipo con el cual se genera la situación. (en el cual para un mensaje de más de 8 KB, el server lo recibe en dos ejecuciones del evento Execute)

Comment: GBM, ahora que revisé las listas de edición, veo que estás editando _mi respuesta_, a lo cual no le encuentro sentido. Como ya mencioné antes en comentarios, de mi parte creo que tu pregunta original ya está respondida. Si tienes más dudas, lo prudente sería publicar nuevas preguntas.

Comment: El sitio te permite editar una respuesta (o una pregunta), pero la intención de esto es mejorar o corregir de alguna manera la pregunta o la respuesta. Hay incluso ediciones por temas de ortografía o redacción que son aprobadas. Pero la edición que has hecho de mi respuesta no conlleva ninguna mejora.